# Spring can only register contructor beans?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

If let's say I have a class `A` (@Component) and a class `B` (@Component). Class `A` needs an instance of `B`. If I put class `B` as a field in A with @Autowired, even though Spring will find the `B` component (through @ComponentScan), the class `A` field will be null. However, if I put `B` as an argument in the `A`'s contructor and annotate the constructor with @Autowired, it will work perfectly.

Is there any way to exclude `B` from `A`'s constructor?

Comment: What do you mean with *eventhough Spring will find the B component, the Class A field will be null*? That's not true. What's your specific question here? Looks like you want/need to fire some method using `B` while creating an instance of `A`.

Comment: why will the field be null? am i missing something here?

Comment: Personally I prefer autowiring the constructor. If only because I can then mock it more easily from my unit tests. But in the real application there shouldn't be any difference between using the constructor autowiring and autowiring the actual variable directly.

Comment: can you give a more concrete example of `A` and `B` ?

Comment: @Ractoc yes there is. Autowiring the field establishes a weak association between A and B (B can be lazily autowired), while constructor parameter establishes a strong association between A and B, and you may say the second is a composition. Also, technically, in the first case you cannot use any method from B during the construction of A, while in the second you can. But to overcome this problem, you may have a `@PostConstruct` method in A that will be fired after A creation and injection.

Comment: Ah, and once again I see there's still more to be learned...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanx a lot for the explication. Yes, that is exactly what happened. I needed to use B in the construction of A and i wasn't able to do that if autowiring field. Only if i autowire the constructor. But that will be messy because i will need many objects autowired(i am working on a java swing application and i need the frames). Can you explain how i should create my PostConstruct method?what should it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @LuiggiMendoza mentioned: Creating a @PostConstruct method is easy: you should only annotate your method with @PostConstruct:

```
public class A {
    @PostConstruct
    void init(){
        //do smth here
    }
}
```

Or if you use XML configuration you can add `init-method` parameter to your bean definition.

Comment: So everithing I wanted to do in constructor, i should do in @PostConstruct method?

Comment: yeah, it will be called right after cunstruction of the Bean